# How to change fragment to acttivity

Tags: android

I want To change my Activity to Fragment I tried hard but I am unable to Change my Activity To Fragment. Can Anyone Please Tell me How to do this? Where To Edit I am new On Android. please tell me And Thanks In Advance how to change activity to fragment

1.I can move from fragment to activity easily.

2 .My problem is how to move from Fragment to activity.
I tried the following code but no use.

```
 `public class Fragmentbell extends Fragment {
LinearLayout linearLayout;
private View root_view;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
private Adapterbell adapterbell;
public static final String EXTRA_OBJC = "key.EXTRA_OBJC";
DbHandler databaseHandler;

private ArrayList<bell> mNotificationList;

private ShimmerFrameLayout lyt_shimmer;
SharedPref sharedPref;
private List<bell> data = new ArrayList<>();

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView( LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState ) {

    root_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bell, container, false);

    loadDataFromDatabase();

    recyclerView = root_view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(1, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new EqualSpacingItemDecoration(0));
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    adapterbell = new Adapterbell(getActivity(), recyclerView, data);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterbell);

    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));



    adapterbell.setOnItemClickListener(( v, obj, position ) -> {


        databaseHandler = new DbHandler(getActivity());

        databaseHandler.updateStatus(data.get(position).getId(), true);


        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).showInterstitialAd();

       Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityNotificationDetail.class);


        Log.v("testti", "" + v.getTag() + " apakah sama " + data.get(position).getpost_id());


        this.startActivity(intent);


    });

    return root_view;
}


private void loadDataFromDatabase() {
    databaseHandler = new DbHandler(getActivity());
    data = databaseHandler.getAllbell();

}







public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    getView().requestFocus();
    getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey( View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event ) {

            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

                Intent intent1 = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent1);

                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
}
```

Adapter

```
`public class Adapterbell extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
 private final int VIEW_ITEM = 1;
 private final int VIEW_PROG = 0;
 private List<bell> items;

private boolean loading;
private OnLoadMoreListener onLoadMoreListener;

private Context context;
private OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;
boolean scrolling = false;

private SharedPref sharedPref;



public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(View view, bell obj, int position);
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(final OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
    this.mOnItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
}

public Adapterbell(Context context, RecyclerView view, List<bell> items) {
    this.items = items;
    this.context = context;
    this.sharedPref = new SharedPref(context);
    lastItemViewDetector(view);
}

public class OriginalViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView category_name;
    public TextView title;
    public ImageView image;
    public ImageView thumbnail_video;
    public MaterialRippleLayout lyt_parent;

    public OriginalViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        category_name = v.findViewById(R.id.category_name);
        title = v.findViewById(R.id.recipe_title);
        image = v.findViewById(R.id.recipe_image);
        thumbnail_video = v.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail_video);
        lyt_parent = v.findViewById(R.id.lyt_parent);
    }

}

public static class ProgressViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ProgressBar progressBar;

    public ProgressViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        progressBar = v.findViewById(R.id.load_more);
    }
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh;
    if (viewType == VIEW_ITEM) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_recipe_list_small, parent, false);
        vh = new OriginalViewHolder(v);
    } else {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_load_more, parent, false);
        vh = new ProgressViewHolder(v);
    }
    return vh;
}

// Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    if (holder instanceof OriginalViewHolder) {
        final bell b = items.get(position);




        final OriginalViewHolder vItem = (OriginalViewHolder) holder;


        vItem.title.setText(b.title);

        if (b.content_type != null && b.content_type.equals("youtube")) {
            Picasso.get()
                    .load(Constant.YOUTUBE_IMAGE_FRONT + b.video_id + Constant.YOUTUBE_IMAGE_BACK_MQ)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_thumbnail)
                    .into(vItem.image);
        } else {
            Picasso.get()
                    .load(sharedPref.getApiUrl() + "/upload/" + b.image)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_thumbnail)
                    .into(vItem.image);
        }

        if (b.content_type != null && b.content_type.equals("Post")) {
            vItem.thumbnail_video.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            vItem.thumbnail_video.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        vItem.lyt_parent.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            if (mOnItemClickListener != null) {
                mOnItemClickListener.onItemClick(view, b, position);
            }
        });

    } else {
        ((ProgressViewHolder) holder).progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
    }

    if (getItemViewType(position) == VIEW_PROG) {
        StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = (StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) holder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.setFullSpan(true);
    } else {
        StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = (StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) holder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.setFullSpan(false);
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (items.get(position) != null) {
        return VIEW_ITEM;
    } else {
        return VIEW_PROG;
    }
}

public void insertData(List<bell> items) {
    setLoaded();
    int positionStart = getItemCount();
    int itemCount = items.size();
    this.items.addAll(items);
    notifyItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount);
}

public void setLoaded() {
    loading = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < getItemCount(); i++) {
        if (items.get(i) == null) {
            items.remove(i);
            notifyItemRemoved(i);
        }
    }
}

public void setLoading() {
    if (getItemCount() != 0) {
        this.items.add(null);
        notifyItemInserted(getItemCount() - 1);
        loading = true;
    }
}

public void resetListData() {
    this.items = new ArrayList<>();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void setOnLoadMoreListener(OnLoadMoreListener onLoadMoreListener) {
    this.onLoadMoreListener = onLoadMoreListener;
}

private void lastItemViewDetector(RecyclerView recyclerView) {

    if (recyclerView.getLayoutManager() instanceof StaggeredGridLayoutManager) {
        final StaggeredGridLayoutManager layoutManager = (StaggeredGridLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                int lastPos = getLastVisibleItem(layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPositions(null));
                if (!loading && lastPos == getItemCount() - 1 && onLoadMoreListener != null) {
                    int current_page = getItemCount() / AppConfig.POST_PER_PAGE;
                    onLoadMoreListener.onLoadMore(current_page);
                    loading = true;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

public interface OnLoadMoreListener {
    void onLoadMore(int current_page);
}

private int getLastVisibleItem(int[] into) {
    int last_idx = into[0];
    for (int i : into) {
        if (last_idx < i) last_idx = i;
    }
    return last_idx;
}
```

}

``

how to movie fragment to acitivity code

Comment: Hey please clarify you want to move/modify from an Activity to a Fragment or vice versa ? you have contradicted yourself at many places, please clarify, thanks.

Comment: @Syed Atif Ali  how to modify fragment to activity change